# Python adding decimals to longitude values

Tags: python, decimal, latitude-longitude

I have thousands of NAD83 latitude longitude values where the longitude values start with a negative like -747559718

this particular coordinate the decimal needs to be at after 4 to be properly used in the mapping application I am using. it should be -74.7559718

There are times where the longitude value will be -123092886 where the decimal should be after the 3. it should be -123.092886

I am reading these coordinates through a JSON file, for some reason they come with no decimals. I am looking for a pure python solution to insert the decimal at the correct place.

The numbers will be 9 or 10 digits long

I know i can do something like once i have my longitude value in a variable

```
 s = longitude
 s[:3] + '.' + s[3:]
```

Comment: if it wasn't for the 9 digit case, you could just multiply by 0.00001

Comment: and why does the `-123.092886` have six decimal places but the `-74.02373` only five?

Comment: How can you differentiate  -3.000000 and -30.00000?

Comment: @taylorswift thats how the coordinates are given in the file. sometimes it has 5 or 6 decimal places

Comment: is it guaranteed that the coordinates will never contain 8 digits, always 7 or 9?

Comment: @taylorswift let me double check the lengths

Comment: @taylorswift the number will always be 9 digits. i am updating the question the first coordinate I put in i left out the last 2 digits i did not think that would matter

Comment: It's very odd that the numbers will always have 9 digits. I mean, coordinates lower than 100 have more precision than the ones >= 100. Are you sure about this? Besides, no way to tell if `-123092886` is `-123.092886` or `-12.3092886`

Comment: there is thousands of them, most are 9 but as I am looking through i see a few with that have 10 digits

Comment: @ziggy Maybe those with 10 digits are the ones >= 100, meaning that all values have 7 decimal places? If all these values don't have a fixed number of decimal places, I don't think this is a deterministic problem at all...

Comment: @lucasnadalutti i may have figured out it, i will post answer if my solution works

Comment: If some are 9 and some are 10, then `int(s) / 1e7` might work, or perhaps `s[:-7] + '.'  + s[-7:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out my problem: all my lat long coordinates are in the contemporaneous US and I know, from being a geospatial analyst that any longitude value in the NAD83 projection that is in the contemporaneous US and starts with the 1 digit, it will have a decimal place after the 3rd digit. and the rest of the longitude values in the US either start with a 7,8 or 9 and those values always have a decimal after the second digit. I am unsure if this solution will work on the rest of the world but it gets it done here

here is my solution with z being the variable containing the longitude value:

```
if str(z)[1:2] == '1':
    longitude = str(z)[0:4]+'.'+str(z)[4::]
else:
    longitude = str(z)[0:3]+'.'+str(z)[3::]
```

**UPDATE**

better answer:

```
longitude = z * 0.0000001
```

this also works for the latitude values

Comment: It looks so wrong I can almost guarantee that's not how those values were built.

Comment: why does it look wrong? it worked. "latitudeE7" : 402212350,
    "longitudeE7" : -747559718 straight from the json file

Comment: It looked wrong because no developer will build numbers by running them through string functions like this. Thus I am sure the number format assumed by your first solution was bound to break on some values. **Your updated solution looks better**, as in _"something a developer could actually write"_. It's also much simpler and developers tend towards the simplest approach that fulfills requirements, thus if your solution is significantly more complex than the problem you are solving, you're usually doing it wrong. Compare complexity and readability of your two solutions ;)